# UpdateProgress not displaying when button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a UpdatePanel inside the UpdatePanel I have "li" and "href" for navigating to another page. After the UpdatePanel I have the updateprogress but it does not work when the "li" gets clicked. I user the UpdateProgress throughout my code for different types of UpdatePanels and it all works the only thing I cannot get to work is if the button or "li" "href" is clicked it does not load the image. Here is my code, What am I missing?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnavcontainer" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="navcontainer" 
            style="border-style: outset; border-width: thin; background-color: #663300; height: 30px; ">                
            <ul id="navlist" runat="server">
                <li runat ="server" id="Home" >
                    <a href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx") %>' title="Home"><span>Home</span></a></li>            
            <%
                if (_ApplicationAccess("Diabetes")) {
                %>
                <li runat ="server" id="Diabetes">
                    <a id="current" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Home/Home.aspx") %>' title="Diabetes"><span>Diabetes</span></a></li> 
                <%
                }
            %>     
            <%
                if (_ApplicationAccess("Dashboard")) {
                %>
                <li runat ="server" id="Dashboard">
                    <a href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Dashboard/Default.aspx") %>' title="Dashboard"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li> 
                <%
                }
            %>       
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:updateprogress associatedupdatepanelid="upnavcontainer" id="upProgessNav" runat="server">
    <progresstemplate>
        <div id="progressBackgroundFilter"></div>
        <div id="processMessage">
                <img alt="Loading" src="App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </progresstemplate>
</asp:updateprogress>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What am I missing?
```

The problem here is that you use direct writes on the web page using the `<%= %>` inside the UpdatePanel.

When you use UpdatePanel, the update needs to be done all on code behind, or else fail, and the reason for that is because on postback he can run only the code behind and can make the render update only by this way.

So to make it work remove the `<%= %>` logic on the aspx part of the page and change them with literals that you render on code behind.

Eg.
Replace all this part with

```
 <%
   if (_ApplicationAccess("Diabetes")) {
  %>
   <li runat ="server" id="Diabetes">
      <a id="current" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Home/Home.aspx") %>' 
         title="Diabetes"><span>Diabetes</span></a></li> 
  <%
  }
 %>
```

with

```
<asp:literal run="server" id="txtDiabetes" />
```

and on code behind.

```
if (_ApplicationAccess("Diabetes")) {
    // render here the output
    txtDiabetes.Text = string.format("<li id=\"Diavetes\" ..... >", ResolveUrl("~/Home/Home.aspx"));
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks much for your reply. I also tried this but it still does not work... It still does not load the image when "HOME" "Diabetes" "Dashboard" buttons are clicked...

Comment: @Nick can you show me the url to maybe see the page and why is that ? Or by your self, can you the real issue, what is actually render ?

Comment: I don't have the url for the page due to its an internal website. I have a very similar progresstemplate running on a treeview and also asp:Button and it works just fine but it just seems like when I run it on the <li> it keeps on not wanting to show up - even with placing the code into a literal...

Comment: I don't know if it would make any difference if this code is in the master page and not in a regular page?

Comment: @Nick I think that you need to debug it step by step to locate what we miss here, maybe the parameter is not found or something like that.

Comment: Do you have couple of min maybe I can set up a chat and I can show you what I currently have?